# Using the Android preference framework without PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a preferences.xml, containing various settings for my app - their possible values\names, defaults, etc.

It was previously used simply in a `PreferenceActivity` with `addPreferencesFromResource()`.

Now I am creating a completely customized settings UI, and I want it to have nothing to do with `PreferenceActivity`.

All I ever want is to have my preference hierarchy from the XML (as `PreferenceScreen`), so I can use it to construct my own UI.
I don't want Android's list adapter, I don't want the dialogs, etc. Only the data model.

Sadly, I haven't found a nice way to do that.
The only close thing I can think of is extending `PreferenceActivity`, providing a custom "R.id.list", and setting its visibility to GONE, so no one will see Android's preference UI.

Any good, clean way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html) directly. First you would call the [setDefaultValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean%29) which does the loading of your preferences XML resource. Next you can get access to the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) by calling [getDefaultSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) and perform any preference changes through the SharedPreferences object. To edit your preferences you will need to get the [Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) from your SharedPreferences object. Make sure to call [commit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) on the editor to actually save the changes you have made.

Comment: That does not answer the question. SharedPreferences allow me to read\write values from the preferences. They don't give me access to the hierarchy in my preferences.xml, including possible entries, defaults, display strings and so on. I don't see a way to programatically instantiate PreferenceManager with my XML without going through a PreferenceActivity.